# ios: leftBarButtonItem.target and .action

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having a Login view controller where I create navigationController, and create `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItems` using custom views (which are `UIButton`). Now here only I set bar button items of `navigationController` so that they can be accessed by all view controller pushed on that navigationController using:

```
navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [someBarButton, someOtherBarButton]
navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton
```

Now for each view controller I set `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBatButtonItem`. I can view the button. Now as the methods for pressing these should be implemented in the view controller I tried this in `viewDidLoad()` of view controller:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.target = self
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.action = Selector("backButtonPressed")
```

But I'm not getting any call backs in the methods:

```
func backButtonPressed() {
    println("Back pressed")
    popViewController()
}
```

**EDIT #1:** Code where I set my leftBarButtonItem in Login view controller:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController()

let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, kNavBarIconHeight, kNavBarIconHeight))
backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "backButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)

navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton
```

I'm using the barButtonItem of navigationController and not the the previous controller in view controller stack

Comment: What does the header of your backButtonPressed() selector method look like?

Comment: @timgcarlson updated the question

Comment: are you sure backbuttonPressed() method is not called ? Can you show the code wherein you set custom button as bar button item.

Comment: To further add to what @JennyJose suggested, try putting a breakpoint in backButtonPressed or print to the console with print().

Comment: Where do you set the `target` and `action` properties?

Comment: @timgcarlson I have kept breakpoint and tried it's not called, am sure that it's not called.

Comment: Same problem for me, have you resolved this issue? I can look correctly my rightBarButton but the action has never been called.

Comment: @weso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124923/ios-leftbarbuttonitem-target-and-action/36358145#36358145

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly I created separate NavigationController class which is subclass of `UINavigationController` where I defined method for each type of button. And within those methods I used `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName` to post appropriate notification for each type of button. To ensure only topmost viewcontroller receives event all viewcontroller register on notification in `viewWillAppear` using

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("buttonPressed"), name: 'button1Notification', object: nil)`

and deregister during `viewWillDisappear` using

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code of setting the custom bar button item like this -

```
    let leftButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) 
    leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40) ; 
    leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"ImageName.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    leftButton.addTarget(self, action: "backButtonClick", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    var leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton)

   self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftBarButtonItem, animated: false);
```

The issue is you are setting a custom button and adding the action on bar button!

Comment: I know that I can set event on UIButton, but I don't want to do this. If I do so I have to implement the method for same in the place where I initialise my navigation controller which is somewhere like AppDelegate. Also I create button there and save them in `navigationController` so that I don't have to create them always in each view controller. Also in some view controller I don't need either of leftBarButtonItem or rightBarButtonItems so I don't set self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem property there.

Answer (score 0):

The back button in a navigation controller is neither the leftBarButtonItem of the top view controller of the stack nor the leftBarButtonItem of the navigation controller. It's the backBarButtonItem of the previous view controller in the stack.

You can change it's title, but unfortunately you can't add a target/selector pair to it (well you can, but it never work).

Comment: it's not so. I had nothing in previous view controller. I have set them only in navigation controller and am sure about it that they are buttons from navigationController only.